# Launching APN settings activity on Lollipop

Tags: android, apn

I am trying to launch APN settings activity from test application in Lollipop.

I have used following code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS);
```

To launch the APN settings activity.

The activity is being launched but the screen does not show any APN list.

Instead it shows as:

> Access Point Name Settings are not available for this user

Following are the logs:

From test application:

```
I/ActivityManager(798): START u0 {act=android.settings.APN_SETTINGS flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings$ApnSettingsActivity} from uid 10066 on display 0
I/ActivityManager(798): Start proc 3273:com.android.settings/1000 for activity com.android.settings/.Settings$ApnSettingsActivity
I/ActivityManager(798): Displayed com.android.settings/.Settings$ApnSettingsActivity: +487ms
```

From device settings:

```
I/ActivityManager(798): Displayed com.android.phone/.MobileNetworkSettings: +395ms
I/ActivityManager(798): START u0 {act=android.settings.APN_SETTINGS cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings$ApnSettingsActivity (has extras)} from uid 1001 on display 0
I/ActivityManager(798): Displayed com.android.settings/.Settings$ApnSettingsActivity: +190ms
```

The only difference I found is that it has extras....

What should contain in extras?

I hope, I will get response..

Comment: Did you try to Google for "Access Point Name Settings are not available for this user" error?

Comment: Joaquin, I tried in Google but i dint find how to launch from test activity. Mentioned as how to do APN setup from settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution by following way..

As I mentioned in query that the difference is "has extras".

sendIntent.putExtra("sub_id", SubscriptionManager.NAME_SOURCE_SIM_SOURCE);

this SubscriptionManager class is introduced in 5.1, and the problem is happening in 5.1 only.

I hope it will help you...